# How to obtain file permissions if I denied myself, but I have admin rights?

Tags: c#, windows-10, .net-framework-version

Let's say I created file `abc.txt` as `User1`

I gave ownership of that file to `User2` and then in Security tab I gave `deny` read/write/exec to `User1`

Now I want to programmatically change that, so `User1` will be owner and have read/write/exec again (I'm running app as `User1`!)

I'm running the app with `Administrator` rights
and the problem is that I'm not even able to do `File.GetAccessControl(path)` because

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: An attempt was made to perform an unauthorized operation.

But, when I click it via GUI -> right -> properties -> security -> advanced

there's button (that requires Administrator rights)

> Click continue in order to attempt to perform that operation with administrator rights

and also

> Change file owner (admin rights required)

And I'm able to do it easily via GUI

But, how exactly I'm supposed to regain my permissions programmatically?

Here`s my current code:

```
//Get Currently Applied Access Control
var fileSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(file.FullName);

//Update it, Grant Current User Full Control
var cu = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
fileSecurity.SetOwner(cu);
fileSecurity.SetAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(cu, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

//Update the Access Control on the File
File.SetAccessControl(file.FullName, fileSecurity);
```

Comment: Use [impersonation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate?view=netframework-4.8).